# Воспроизведение звука по нажатию клавиши или по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, аудио, qsound

Как можно реализовать, в приложении на *PyQt5*, возможность воспроизведения звука по нажатию клавиши или по нажатию кнопки?

Comment: примите ответ если он вам помог галочка слева от ответа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант.

Класс `QSound` предоставляет метод для воспроизведения звуковых файлов `.wav`

Для простого и быстрого воспроизведения аудиофайлов `wav` используйте класс QSound
и вызовите метод play():

1. Передайте путь к файлу wav, чтобы создать экземпляр класса QSound;
2. Подключите сигнал кнопки к функции слота play(),
   чтобы при каждом нажатии кнопки воспроизводился звук.

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QSound
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton


class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()

        self.sound = QSound('eff/cl.wav', self)              # 1         

        self.play_btn = QPushButton('Play Sound', self)
        self.play_btn.clicked.connect(self.sound.play)       # 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]